# fancybox iframe dimension

Tags: jquery, fancybox, dynamic-resizing

In the fancybox homepage (http://fancybox.net/home) there is an example that opens an iFrame dimensioned as the 75% of the screen.

I can't get it by modifying the width and height properties on the .js file as described on the site.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$('iframeLink').fancybox({
'width':300,
'height':200,
'type':'iframe',
'autoScale':'false'
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi I just read through all of these and I had to take bits and pieces of what everyone else wrote to get it to work. I wanted a window 600 by 410

***First change the java script*** I dealt with the file: **jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js** (this may change with later versions)
under defaults set your height and width

width : 600,
height : 410,

***then change the script on your webpage**

$("#various3").fancybox({

**'width'               : 600,**

**'height'          : 410,**

'autoScale'         : false,

'type'              : 'iframe'

**please note the size is not in single quotes!**  I wasted an hour before I saw this mistake.

This should help.  Now if someone can tell me how to get this iframe to pop up on page load.

Comment: "please note the size is not in single quotes!" -fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you should set the fancybox height as

```
$(window).height() * 0.75
```

but I would personally prefer to do it with pixels like

```
$(window).height() - 80
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up adjusting the default dimensions at the bottom of the fancybox js file - "frameWidth:800,frameHeight:600"

They also mention you can do this [on the fancybox site](http://fancybox.net/api):

> You can pass options as key/value
>   object to fancybox() function or
>   modify them at the bottom of FancyBox
>   JS file

Answer (score 0):

but my fancybox work with ajax and so i can't change fancy size !

`$('iframeLink').fancybox({
'width':300,
'height':200,
'type':'ajax',
'autoScale':'false'
});`

Answer (score 0):

I've got version 2.14 and this is what works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    'padding' : 0,  
    'autoSize': false,      
    'width': 650, 
    'height': 520
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By simply changing the value of type from 'iframe' to 'ajax' , solve the problem .

```
$('Selector').fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'ajax',  //from type : 'iframe',
                padding : 0     
            });
```

Now it use the height & width of class described for the body of iframe.html file. So auto manipulated.