# FancyBox iFrame Issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I playing with FancyBox and stumbling about the following issue:

I try to open a Website inside a iFrame by using this code

```
<a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.golem.de">Iframe</a>
```

which works fine, but if I want to use a image instead the "Iframe" text it just open a white box:

```
<a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.golem.de"><img scr="img/1.jpg"></a>
```

Any advise?

Comment: use javascript to declare iframe type , [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464870/fancybox-iframe-dimension)

Comment: You have a typo: `<img scr="" ...` should be `<img src="" ...`; is that what you meant with "white box"?

Comment: No, just a mistype :) but you are right, i want to use a thumbnail to fire the fancy box iframe

Comment: then I don't see any issue with your code ... you are using fancybox v2.x, aren't you? does it fire OK without the thumbnail? got any link?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the official documentation about this problem: http://fancybox.net/. Take a look at the "Examples of manual call" in the demo page (home page). By the way, the iframe option is mostly used to display external content, not an image, which you can always display using the default options.

Comment: I want to display external content, look at my example. I only want the image to be the Link Object for the iFrame.

Comment: he just wants to use a thumbnail to fire the fancybox iframe